# Hyperledger fabric difference between submit transaction and evaluate transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using the hyper-ledger fabric network with 2 organisation and chain-code also installed on the network its working. I came across submitTransaction and EvaluateTransaction in fabric node js. what is difference between them, what i observer is.

- When i initiate ***contract.submittransaction*** the submitTransaction from the fabric-node even though if i call the query method from the chain-code its create the new block and chain-code query method don't have put-state
- If  i use ***contract.evaluateTransaction*** the evaluate transaction from the fabric-node to query method its does not create any transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `submitTransaction` vs `evaluateTransaction` is that `submitTransaction` takes the proposal results returned from invoking the smart contract and submits them to the orderer and waits for the transaction to be committed. This means that the proposal results will be ordered and delivered to the peers for validation and committed to the blockchain.

It is irrespective of what the smart contract transaction does, however the general pattern is that `submitTransaction` is used for transactions that change the world state and `evaluateTransaction` is used for transactions that only query the world state (or query key history).

However it's perfectly reasonable for example to want to record querying of the world state onto the ledger and so you would use `submitTransaction` on a smart contract function that doesn't modify the world state in order to do this.

Comment: Thanks for replay david. Why its necessary to create the block, for query the ledger, any use case ?

Comment: One use case I can think of would be to have an audit trail of all access to the world state.

Answer (score -1):

**contract.submittransaction** execute the transaction against the chain code that's why it creates the new block. while **contract.evaluateTransaction**  only query the state database that's why don't create the new block.

Comment: means its just do transaction on the blockchain ledger, but it does not update the world state ?

Comment: it's just a ledger query it does not create a new transaction